# It ain't Christmas yet!

Tags: bug

It's mid-afternoon on Christmas eve. Indeed, I am still at work.

So why do I have a hat which claims I posted/voted on Christmas day?!

Comment: you're not alone...merry X-mas anyway!

Comment: Happy Christmas yourself! (And I hope you have a very merry new year also.)

Comment: Because Doc Brown put the servers in the DeLorean and set the time two days into the past!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think you have been having too much DeLorean yourself - two days would be yesterday...

Comment: Sorry, I was always under the impression that Christmas is the 25th. See, we never really celebrate Christmas in Israel... So make it two days back, and then one day a head. I mean you want the server to go *Back to the Future*, don't you? ;-)

Comment: I got two of them.  I am tempted to register for several more sites and increase my collection.

Comment: @Asaf I'm confused. Today is the 24th. Tomorrow is the 25th, which is Christmas Day. I thought you meant Doc Brown put the servers in his car tomorrow and set the time two days into the past, meaning today (so, yesterday). What did you actually mean?

Comment: I am severely sleep deprived, because I stayed up almost the entire night reading QC. I don't have to make sense!

Comment: Furthermore, sometimes some of my "Achievements" from today are listed under *Yesterday* ... I assumed because it was already yesterday somewhere.

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug! ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748/161676

Comment: @AsafKaragila what is QC?

Comment: @Asaf: You are so funny..

Comment: @draks: You brought this on yourself, remember. [See this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12184/does-that-count-as-defacement?noredirect=1#comment47518_12184).

Comment: @Asaf I don't see me involved in the post you linked...

Comment: @draks: What? I'm not as tired as when I made those comments, but I'm still tired enough so I won't be legally responsible for the content of anything I write!

Comment: It's always Christmas *somewhere*... (Maybe not.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blame it on time zones. It's Christmas day in Japan.

Comment: It wasn't at the time some people got their hats.  But I think it was in New Zealand and certainly in Karibati